# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6' на Windows

Tags: python, windows, установка, pyside6

Пытаюсь задействовать Qt для Python
Нашел инструкцию по установке:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/quickstart.html
Делаю все так, как там, но не получается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

`pip install pyside6` отработал без ошибок, все нужные пакеты установились.
Однако когда я в коде пишу:

```py
import PySide6.QtCore
```

то получаю ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'

Ошибку получаю как в Python, запущенном из командной строки, так и при запуске из IDLE.
Может нужно куда-то путь к пакетам прописывать?
`PYTHONPATH` и `PYTHONHOME` у меня указывают на папку с Python:
`PYTHONHOME=C:\Python311`, `PYTHONPATH=C:\Python311`

PySide6 есть в каталоге `C:\Python311\env\Lib\site-packages`.

Comment: Какой версией Python вы запускаете файл?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить pip install с правами админа, может быть решит проблему

Comment: Запустил от админа, результат тот же.

Comment: Python 3.11.3  x64

Comment: У вас какая-то путаница с python и пакетами. Я с таким сталкивался когда python был установлен из Windows Store. Т.е. я бы сделал следующее: 1) проверил сколько и каких python вообще стоит - удалил все, кроме установленного с python.org; 2) далее из командной строки, делаем "pip list" - убеждаемся, что там есть PySide, после этого запускаем там же python, далее в его командной строке делаем import. Если всё прошло без ошибок, значит нормально всё.